# .htaccess Parameters to $_GET failing when directory exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters, get

My .htaccess is as follows.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My issue is that there's a directory, say "test" that exists in the root of the directory.  When I go to /test, it will redirect to /test?url=test rather than hiding it as usual.  I'm wondering if there's a way around this.  I would really prefer to not rename or move the directory causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off the DirectorySlash.

Try adding the following line to your htaccess :

```
DirectorySlash off
```

This will allow you to rewrite /test (without trailing slash) to /index.php?url=test.

Comment: Is there any way to (without enabling indexes) push them to the index file, or rewrite them to /dir/ instead of /dir where they would get access denied?  I don't want to enable indexes because I don't really wanna list out the files there, but it would kind'a suck to leave them on a permission denied page.  I feel like I'm wanting it both ways.